# Load html body content in fixed size columns

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I want to split content of a html file into several fixed size(height and width) columns and load it in Webview. I tried using below mentioned css property, but could manage to get it work

`-webkit-column-width: 275px;
 -webkit-column-height: 500px;`

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `column-height` property. But you can set the height using the good old fashioned `height:500px;`